# Increasing programming efficiency to O(n) from O(n^2)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Let's say you have an array of numbers and a queries array:

```
array = [1,3,5,6,9]
queries = [5,9,3]
```

We need to find the number of operations required i.e. add 1 or subtract 1 from the array to bring all numbers of the array to match the element from the queries array.

For example:

- For query 5, number of operations required to bring all elements of array to 5 is abs(1-5) + abs(3-5) + abs(5-5) + abs(6-5) + abs(9-5) = 4+2+0+1+4 = 11.
- For query 9, it would be 21.
- For query 3 it would be 13.

Is there a way to do this with time complexity better than O(len(array) x len(queries)) ?

My function to do this in python is as follows

```
def find_min_costs(array,queries):
    for query in queries:
        cost = 0
        for arr in array:
            cost+= abs(arr-query)
        print(cost,end = ' ')
```

but the time complexity of my code is O(len(array) x len(queries))

I would like to do this with a better time complexity such as O(len(array))

Comment: Note: This is only `O(n^2)` when both lists are the same size. Otherwise, this is already `O(larger_length_N)`

Comment: It is possible at least in O((len(array) + len(queries)) * log(len(array))).

Comment: @Gassa I'm keen to know what that solution looks like.

Comment: maybe sorting the queries and using results for smaller queries for the bigger queries?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, agreed, I am trying to to find a solution that does not involve traversing both arrays since that is the worst time complexity, ideally looking for an O(n) or O(nlog n) time complexity solution

Comment: Could you do `for i in range(len(queries))` + `for j in range(i, len(array))`, maybe?

Answer (score 7):

Sort the input array (if it is not sorted already).

Now, for every query `q`, find the position `pos` where the query number would be placed in the array (use binary search).

Next, observe that, for all numbers to the left, `array[1], ..., array[pos]`, their impact would be `q - array[i]`. The total is `pos * q - sum_of_array_from_1_to_pos`.

Similarly, for all numbers to the right, `array[pos+1], ..., array[n]`, their impact would be `array[i] - q`. The total is `sum_of_array_from_pos+1_to_n - (n-pos) * q`.

If you compute prefix sums of the sorted array in advance, the above quantities can be found in O(1).

In total, the preparation step is sorting the array in O(n log n), where n is the length of the array.
Then computing prefix sums in O(n).

For each query, the work can be done in O(log n) for binary search and then O(1) for computing the answer. The total is O(m log n), where m is the number of queries and n is the length of the array.

---

How to use prefix sums: if we have prefix sums `p[i] = array[1] + array[2] + ... + array[i]`, then a quantity like `sum_of_array_from_x_to_y` is just `p[y] - p[x-1]`.

How to compute prefix sums: `p[0] = 0`, `p[i] = p[i - 1] + array[i]`.

Comment: That's incredible @Gassa, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I think this can be seen as a conservative vector field's potential energy.

Comment: @VikashSabnani it will be incredible since cf grandmaster answered.